# HTML coding request from my professor and I don't follow

Tags: javascript, html

I submitted this assignment and my professor replied back: *Need to modify the processLink function to add background to the links.*
Is she asking for me to change the way Reddit and the Skyrim Nexus sites display? I have provided the link to the site as well.

LINK: http://wmelliott.x10host.com/Week4/Fig12_14.html#something

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/?">Skyrim Special Edition</a>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a>

  <div id="links">
  </div>

<script>
  var arr = [], linkList = document.links;
  var contents = "<ul>";
  for(var i=0; i<linkList.length; i++){
    var currentLink = linkList[i];
    contents += "<li><a href='" + currentLink.href + "'>" +currentLink.innerHTML + "</li>";

  }
  contents += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById( "links").innerHTML = contents;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, that's what she is asking about. You should probably add some styles to the links

Comment: Why are you inserting links using strings? `document.createElement` makes things look a lot nicer.. then again, it's not like there's a problem with your code, so this comment is kind of irrelevant.. sorry

Comment: Adding the `style` attribute might help you out when styling your `<a>` tags btw.

Comment: Thank you Usman & Ty Q, the course I am taking is has been pared down from a 16 week standard university semester to an 8 week term. I am literally just trying to get week 2 and 3 understood much less week 6 we are in. If this course was not *required* I would have avoided it like the plague and taught myself and a more leisurely pace so I could get it. The code above I got quite a bit of help with. (thank you cuz). I have a couple weeks left and then will start over re-learning the web languages... appropriately. Anyway, thank you all. I used the style links below, maybe it will be okay. TY!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, but it may help!

Using the `style` attribute you can implement CSS without adding `<style>` or linking an external stylesheet. You can also set the styles with JavaScript, but honestly, you'd probably only want to do that when using `document.createElement` unless you want the effects to be global or you want to apply it after the `for` loop.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a href="https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/?">Skyrim Special Edition</a>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a>

  <div id="links">
  </div>

<script>
  var arr = [], linkList = document.links;
  var contents = "<ul>";
  for(var i=0; i<linkList.length; i++){
    var currentLink = linkList[i];
    contents += "<li><a title='dank title' style='color: red; text-decoration: none;' href='" + currentLink.href + "'>" +currentLink.innerHTML + "</li>";

  }
  contents += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById( "links").innerHTML = contents;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again Ty Q. haha want to come take my final for me..haha. That ought to be something for me to Epically bomb.  Your the man.

Comment: @Mereinid As fun as that sounds, I'd have to decline. Have a good day.